# How can we get stock data in product listing via afterGetList plugin in Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2, event-observer, plugin, magento2.2.3

Since magento 2.2.3 is displaying out of stock items in product listing, I would like to get the qty attribute in the listing using rest API. I'm using afterGetList plugin.

di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface">
    <plugin name="get_product_metrics" type="Custom\Module\Plugin\ProductGet"/>
</type>
```

Custom/Module/etc/extension_attributes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface">
        <attribute code="qty" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

ProductGet.php

```
 <?php

namespace Custom\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;

class ProductGet{
protected $productExtensionFactory;
protected $productFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionFactory $productExtensionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockItem,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterface $mediaGallery,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
)
{
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->logger = $logger;
    $this->stockItem = $stockItem;
    $this->productExtensionFactory = $productExtensionFactory;
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    $this->mediaGallery = $mediaGallery;
}

public function afterGet(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $subject,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product){

    $this->logger->info("Inside AfterGet ");

    $imageUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

    if($product->getImage()){
        $product->setCustomAttribute("image", $imageUrl.'catalog/product'.$product->getImage());
    }

    return $product;
}


/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $subject
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $products
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
    public function afterGetList(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $subject,
    $products
    )
    {
        $this->logger->info("list: ".json_encode($products->getItems()));
        /** @var  $product */
        foreach ($products->getItems() as $key => $product) {
            $qty = $this->stockItem->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
            $extensionattributes = $product->getExtensionAttributes();
            $extensionattributes->setQty($qty);
            $product->setExtensionAttributes($extensionattributes);
        }
        return $products;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to assign custom qty value in foreach?

Comment: @RohanHapani No, I want to get the qty attribute for each product in a collection. I need this in product listing rest api

Comment: Can you please upload your full plugin code?

Comment: @RohanHapani I have edited the question please check.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know.

Comment: @RohanHapani Please check the comment

Comment: Which api you are using for the product listing?

Comment: @RakeshVarma <Host>/rest/{{store_code}}/V1/products?searchCriteria[pageSize]=20

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Your `extension_attributes` class is wrong check my `extension_attributes.xml` file

Comment: Thankyou very much! I have updated the question and its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add qty attribute using `extension_attributes.xml`. Here is the code for that

create `extension_attributes.xml` in `etc/` folder of your module.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">

<extension_attributes for="Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface">
    <attribute code="qty" type="string"/>
</extension_attributes>
```

and add this code in your `afterGetList()`

```
public function afterGetList(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $subject,
    $products
) {
    foreach ($products->getItems() as $key => $product) {
        $qty = $this->stockItem->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
        $extensionattributes = $product->getExtensionAttributes();
        $extensionattributes->setQty($qty);
        $product->setExtensionAttributes($extensionattributes);
    }
    return $products;
}
```

You can get more idea from here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I tried this extension attributes also. I have compiled and upgrade. But it is throwing an exception Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\\Catalog\\Api\\Data\\ProductExtension::setQty() in

Comment: remove generated folder and try again. because I have tested above code and I get qty in extension_attributes array

Comment: and if possible update your question with `extension_attributes.xml` file with its location.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check. Also I have removed the folder, even the result is same

Comment: extension attribute class is wrong use this class `Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using plugin, you can directly copy list.phtml from 
**vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml**

to

**app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml**

and add following code

```
$_product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem()->getQty();
```

I am using the same and its perfectly working fine.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But my application is mobile based and I need to use rest apis. I need qty where ever the products list/collection loads

Comment: Try,
/V1/stockItems/:productSku . 
For more details, you can refer https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/list.html#cataloginventory

Comment: I know there is an api. I need the qty in the product listing. I cant loop all the products and call the stock api to get it. Anyways I got the solution. Thanks! for replying.

Comment: This isn't working for me in Magento 2.4, looks like the stock extension attribute is not their on the product

Answer (score 1):

You can get each product's qty by using this below code :

```
foreach ($products->getItems() as $key => $product) {
    $stockItem = $product->getExtensionAttributes()->getStockItem();
    print_r($stockItem->getQty());
}
```

---

**EDIT :**

You can set it by this below code :

```
$product->setStockData(['qty' => $stockItem, 'is_in_stock' => (bool)$stockItem]);
$product->setQuantityAndStockStatus(['qty' => $stockItem, 'is_in_stock' => (bool)$stockItem]);
$product->save();
```

Hope, It will helpful for you.

Comment: I'm able to get the quantity in the loop. My question is how to set back to the collection so that products list rest api will show the qty

Comment: No. I didn't worked

Comment: Is there any error log or system log?

Comment: Actually when I run this, I got empty list in the rest api. When I see the admin console the quantity is showing as null. Again I have added the qty and list is displayed in rest api