# Magento 2 REST API: Get the name of child products in bundle_product_options-> product_links

Tags: magento2, rest-api, plugin, bundled-product, after-plugin

So I am trying to go for a headless magento approach.

I am using the following API to get product details:

> V1/products/:sku

If the product is a bundle product, it shows bundle_product_options in the response as follows:

```
"bundle_product_options": [
        {
            "option_id": 6,
            "title": "Option Title",
            "required": true,
            "type": "select",
            "position": 1,
            "sku": "Option SKU",
            "product_links": [
                {
                    "id": "52",
                    "sku": "Child Product SKU",
                    "option_id": 6,
                    "qty": 1,
                    "position": 1,
                    "is_default": false,
                    "price": 0,
                    "price_type": 0,
                    "can_change_quantity": 1
                },
```

I want to add the following information in the product_links section:

> **Child Product Name** and
>   **Child Product quantity left in stocks**

I have created a plugin as follows:

> etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <type name="\Magento\Bundle\Api\ProductLinkManagementInterface">
         <plugin name="get_linked_product_metrics" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\LinkedProductGet"/>
      </type>
   </config>
```

> etc/extension_attribute.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
      <extension_attributes for="Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\LinkInterface">
          <attribute code="stockQty" type="string"/>
      </extension_attributes>

      <extension_attributes for="Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\LinkInterface">
          <attribute code="name" type="string"/>
       </extension_attributes>
  </config>
```

> Vendor/Module/Plugin/LinkedProductGet.php

```
<?php

   namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

   use Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\LinkInterface;

   class LinkedProductGet{
      protected $productExtensionFactory;
      protected $productFactory;

      public function __construct(
         \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductExtensionFactory $productExtensionFactory,
         \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
         \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockItem,
         \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
         \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
      )
     {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->stockItem = $stockItem;
        $this->productExtensionFactory = $productExtensionFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
     }

     /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $subject
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $products
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
     public function afterGetProductLinks(
         \Magento\Bundle\Api\ProductOptionRepositoryInterface $subject,
         $products
     )
     {
         /** @var  $product */
         foreach ($products->getItems() as $key => $product) {

                 $title = $this->getName();
                 $extensionattributes = $product->getExtensionAttributes();
                 $extensionattributes->setName($title);
                 $product->setExtensionAttributes($extensionattributes);
                 $qty = $this->stockItem->getStockQty($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
                 $extensionattributes = $product->getExtensionAttributes();
                 $extensionattributes->setStockQty($qty);
                 $product->setExtensionAttributes($extensionattributes);
         }
         return $products;
      }
   }
```

But I am getting no extra field in the desired section. What could I be doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated!

I used this guide: [How can we get stock data in product listing via afterGetList plugin in Magento 2.2.3](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248140/how-can-we-get-stock-data-in-product-listing-via-aftergetlist-plugin-in-magento/248160)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced the same problem. Here is my code:

> etc/di.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <type name="Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\LinksList">
        <plugin name="get_bundle_product_child_name" type="Chihuo\WechatApp\Plugin\ChildName"/>
    </type>
   </config>
```

> etc/extension_attribute.xml

```xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">

    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Bundle\Api\Data\LinkInterface">
        <attribute code="name" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
  </config>
```

> Plugin/ChildName.php

```php
<?php
namespace Vender\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\InventorySalesAdminUi\Model\GetSalableQuantityDataBySku;
use Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\GetProductSalableQtyInterface;

class ChildName
{
    protected $productRepository;
    protected $getSalableQuantityDataBySku;
    protected $getProductSalableQty;
    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        GetSalableQuantityDataBySku $getSalableQuantityDataBySku,
        GetProductSalableQtyInterface $getProductSalableQty
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->getSalableQuantityDataBySku = $getSalableQuantityDataBySku;
        $this->getProductSalableQty = $getProductSalableQty;
    }

    public function afterGetItems(
        \Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\LinksList $subject,
       $childrenList
    ) {
        foreach ($childrenList as $child) {
            $linkExtension = $child->getExtensionAttributes();
            $sku = $child->getSku();
            $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);
            $linkExtension->setName($product->getName());
            $child->setExtensionAttributes($linkExtension);
        }
        return $childrenList;
    }
}
```

Stock Qty could be set in the same strategy.
Hope this helps.